# MobX async reaction

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, store, mobx

Hi I'm using MobX in a store and I need to have an async reaction when a computed value has changed:

```
class Store {
    @observable user;
    @observable something;

    @computed get firstParam () {
         return this.user && this.user.params[0];
    }

    async loadSomething () {
        reaction(
                () => this.firstParam,
                async (param) => {
                    const { data: something } = await axios.get(`url/${param}`);

                    runInAction('update state after fetching something', () => {
                        this.something = something;
                    });
                }
            );
     }

}
```

I was wondering what would be the difference here with using `when` instead of `reaction` apart from the running condition ?

```
when(
    () => !!this.firstParam,
    async () => {
         // fetch using this.firstParam
    }
)
```

Comment: How did you get this working on your machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `when` executes it's effect only *once* and then stops. So in your case the data would only be fetched once.

Answer (score 4):

```
        reaction(
            () => this.firstParam,
            async (param) => {
                const { data: something } = await axios.get(`url/${param}`);

                runInAction('update state after fetching something', () => {
                    this.something = something;
                });
            }
        );
```

This will track just `this.firstParam` and when that return a new data it will call

```
            async (param) => {
            const { data: something } = await axios.get(`url/${param}`);

            runInAction('update state after fetching something', () => {
                this.something = something;
            });
```

Now, If you go with `when` I believe it would end up doing the same,
Taken from mobx docs:

> You can use observable data structures as a promise... After completing the asynchronous action, just update your data

So i see no reason why not to use `when` in your case.